# MySQL load/stress testing

Tags: mysql, load-testing

I am going to do load testing on mysql server, could someone recommend good metrics to concentrate on? Any automated way(read software) of getting/tracking them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to concentrate on MySql metrics, I highly recommend you utilize mysqlreport.  It's available here and will generate alot of information as well as provides a How-To interpret the results.

Link: http://hackmysql.com/mysqlreport

Answer (score 2):

For stress testing you should give [MySQL Super Smack](http://vegan.net/tony/supersmack/) a go.

> Super Smack is a benchmarking, stress testing, and load generation tool for MySQL (and PostgreSQL). Super Smack was originally written by Sasha Pachev, and then hosted and maintained by Jeremy Zawodny.

As well as [MySQLReport](http://hackmysql.com/mysqlreport) mention by @jeffp711, you should keep a close eye on your OS level stats using `mpstat`, `vmstat` and `iostat`

Answer (score 1):

The best metric is "how fast does your production queries run".  MySQL server performance is 99% governed by how good your schema and queries are.

Comment: ah, unfortunately i have no control over that :(

Answer (score 1):

Tech Republic in, "How do I... Stress test MySQL with mysqlslap?" covered using mysqlslap for performance testing:

> The mysqlslap utility makes it possible to benchmark and compare MySQL
>   performance on different hardware, as well as accurately quantify the
>   effect of a change in database design. This tutorial shows how you can
>   use mysqlslap to run tests involving multiple clients, custom queries,
>   different table engines, and much more.

Source: [Techrepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/howdoi/how-do-i-stress-test-mysql-with-mysqlslap/133)

Answer (score 0):

The DBT2 Benchmark Tool can be used to run automated benchmarks for MySQL and MySQL Cluster. It supports three types of benchmarks:

DBT2
SysBench
flexAsynch

link:https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/benchmarks.html