# max_connections for 8GB RAM and shared server

Tags: mysql, settings

I just wanted to ask what would be a good number in my.cnf in MySQL for max_connections?

I have a shared server which has about 10 websites and 8GB RAM and a quad-core processor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get the best results by reviewing answers regarding [MySQL load/stress testing](https://serverfault.com/questions/31933/mysql-load-stress-testing) and [MySQL performance tuning](https://serverfault.com/questions/53266/how-to-fine-tune-our-mysql-server) and then building on your firsthand experience to find the optimal `max_connections` value for your situation.